AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'getevn'. Did you mean: 'getenv'? Подскажите, что не так?
Ошибка:
Running] python -u "c:\Users\Машуля\Новая папка\app.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\������\����� �����\app.py", line 14, in <module>
    bot = Bot(token=os.getevn('TOKEN'))
                    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'getevn'. Did you mean: 'getenv'?

[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.956 seconds

Код:
import asyncio
import os
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart

from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

from handlers.user_private import user_private_router


ALLOWED_UPDATES = ['message','edited_message']

bot =Bot(token = os.geteven('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher()

dp.include_router(user_private_router)



async def main():
     await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
     await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=ALLOWED_UPDATES)


asyncio.run(main())


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Выдает ошибку, у  модуль os  нет атрибута geteven
Вопрос как устранить эту ошибку?

Почему, эта ошибка выдается?

Полный код прикрепил

У вас прям в ошибке написано что нет атрибута getevn, и может быть вы имели в виду getenv. У Вас опечатка в 14 строчке, как и указано в ошибке:
bot =Bot(token = os.geteven('TOKEN'))

замените на:
bot = Bot(token = os.getenv('TOKEN'))


Старайтесь сами анализировать ошибки, это не так сложно как кажется, особенно когда в ней уже содержится ответ на Ваш вопрос.
